# Issues with form.validate_on_submit()

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a page that allows a user to edit their profile.  But I'm having an issue where validate_on_submit is returning false (I think).  The only time it's working is when a new user profile pic is uploaded.  But if I try editing the other fields clicking submit does nothing.  If I remove the image upload parts then the submit button starts working normally.

Here's my code.  Sorry for the amount code but I wanted to give as clear a picture as possible.  If more info is needed please ask.

UPDATE:  I moved my image upload code into it's own form.  This allowed validate_on_submit to work for my submit button.

UPDATE #2:  I found the ultimate issue was the `request.files` returning nothing when the user wasn't editing their profile picture.  I just had to do a simple check to see if `request.files` returned anything.

```
userImage = request.files['fileUpload']
if userImage.filename:
    # Do stuff
```

Model:

```
class EditProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    outX1 = HiddenField()
    outY1 = HiddenField()
    outX2 = HiddenField()
    outY2 = HiddenField()
    outW = HiddenField()
    outH = HiddenField()
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = EmailField(('Email'), validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    job_title = StringField('Job Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    department = StringField('Department', validators=[DataRequired()])    
    start_date = DateField("Start Date", format="%Y-%m-%d",
                           default=datetime.today,
                           validators=[DataRequired()])
    current_employee = BooleanField("Current Employee")    
    fileUpload = FileField('Employee Image',
                               validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(images, 'Images only!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Update Profile')

    def __init__(self, original_email, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['csrf_enabled'] = False
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_email = original_email

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data != self.original_email:
            employee = Employee.query.filter_by(email=self.email.data).first()
            if employee is not None:
                raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

Route:

```
@bp.route('/edit_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfileForm(current_user.email)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        current_user.first_name = form.first_name.data
        current_user.last_name = form.last_name.data
        current_user.job_title = form.job_title.data
        current_user.department = form.department.data
        current_user.start_date = form.start_date.data
        current_user.current_employee = form.current_employee.data

        userImage = request.files['fileUpload']
        x1 = request.form.get('outX1')
        y1 = request.form.get('outY1')
        x2 = request.form.get('outX2')
        y2 = request.form.get('outY2')
        width = request.form.get('outW')
        height = request.form.get('outH')
        image_name = imageManip.cropNsave(userImage, form.email.data, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        current_user.image_name = image_name

        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your changes have been saved.')
        return redirect(url_for('main.edit_profile'))

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        print ("LOADING PROFILE PAGE")
        form.email.data = current_user.email
        form.first_name.data = current_user.first_name
        form.last_name.data = current_user.last_name
        form.job_title.data = current_user.job_title
        form.department.data = current_user.department
        form.start_date.data = current_user.start_date
        form.current_employee.data = current_user.current_employee
        imageName = current_user.image_name
        imagePath = Config.STATIC_IMG_PATH + current_user.image_name
    return render_template('edit_profile.html', title='Edit Profile',
                           form=form,
                           imagePath=imagePath,
                           imageName=imageName)
```

HTML:

```
{% block app_content %}
    <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
    <form id="cropForm">
        <div id="overlay-container" class="popup-overlay">
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="cropbtn" name="crop" type="submit" value="Click to Crop!">
            </div>
            <div id="image-holder">
                <img id="output_image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">        
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" role="form">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
                    {{form.first_name(class="form-control")}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                    {{form.last_name(class="form-control")}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                    {{form.email(class="form-control")}}
                </div>

                </br>

                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label" for="job_title">Job Title</label>
                    {{form.job_title(class="form-control")}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label" for="department">Department</label>
                    {{form.department(class="form-control")}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  required"><label class="control-label" for="start_date">Start Date</label>   
                    {{form.start_date(class="form-control")}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="current_employee">Current Employee? &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>   
                    {{ form.current_employee }}
                </div> 
                {{form.submit(class="btn btn-default")}}
            </div>
        </form>
        <form>
            <div class="col-md-4">                
                <img id="imageSrc" hidden="true" src="{{ imagePath }}">
                <label class="control-label" for="employee_image">Employee Photo</label>
                <br>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <label id="browsebutton" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" for="fileUpload">
                            {{ form.fileUpload(id="fileUpload", type="file", value="") }}
                            Browse...
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="image_name" name="image_name" readonly="readonly" type="text" value=" {{imageName}}" >
                    </div>                                
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="360" height="450"></canvas>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cropped-image-content">
                        <img id="cropped_image"</img>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>            
        </form>        
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You have access to `{{ form.errors }}` in your template to see what the validation failures were-- rather then just guessing.  Also helpful if you include the form code to see what validation you're requiring.

Comment: @Doobeh Thanks for the tip!  I'll give that a try too, but I think that Nick K9 has the right idea about my request.files being empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I don’t see any error handling around the image. What happens if `request.files` is empty, for example? I think if you make this code more robust, the problem will be resolved.

Comment: Ah!  I never considered what happens if I'm not uploading a new image while editing the profile.  I'll give that a try.  As for making it more robust, I'm pretty new to flask/webdev so I'm learning it as I go.  So this is me trying to make my program more robust.  It's not yet at the release stage.  :)

Comment: So I don't think the `request.files` is the issue.  I commented out everything under `if form.validate_on_submit():` except for a print statement.  It's still not returning true.

Comment: I see you're using both [`csrf_token`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) and [`hidden_tag()`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm.hidden_tag). If you use the second one, it seems that you don't need to use the first. Could that be the issue? What were the errors listed in `{{ form.errors }}` as suggested by Doobeh? It would be helpful to see the FlaskForm subclass.

Comment: I removed the csrf_token but that didn't help.  Also `form.errors` isn't returning anything.  It seems like there aren't any errors being thrown.  I'm currently trying to work through the logic in my html code since it seems like something is going on there.  If I comment out the image upload section the my submit validates.  I'm thinking that maybe it has something to do with another button being used in my image upload code is conflicting with my submit button.

Comment: Well, MDN says that when the upload is nested inside the label, the `for` attribute [isn't needed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Have you tried using the sibling-elements approach instead of nesting? Either should work, but… who knows? Still think it would be useful to see the FlaskForm subclass you've declared.

Comment: To be honest that's something I picked up from another example I found for doing image uploading.  It was a way to get a button with a un-editable text box next to it and make it look good.  I'm also not familiar with the "sibling-elements" approach.  But I'll look into that.  HTML.CSS/JS are all still pretty new to me so my methodology is going to be crap and reliant on my google abilities.  I also updated my question and added my models class....I'm assuming that's what you were asking for?

Comment: Apologies, I missed that somehow. I can't see the issue TBH. Maybe try removing the FileField validators and then add them back one at a time?

Comment: No worries, I just made the edit.  So I was able to get around the validate_on_submit issue by putting the image upload code into it's own <form>.  That uncovered some other issues in my code but I think I have a handle on that issue.  I'm going to consider this issue addressed.  Thanks for your input!